# Is it safe to use a 50W light in a 35W hood range?

Tags: lighting, kitchens

One of the halogen lights on my hood fan just stopped working. The existing fan, and the enclosure, mention that it should be a `GU10 120V 35W` light. I replaced it with a `GU10 120V 50W` light.

Is this safe?

Comment: Here's [a similar question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4849/is-it-generally-safe-to-use-a-lower-wattage-bulb-in-a-light-fixture-specifical) that asks about using a lower-wattage bulb. [Here's](http://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/ge-35w-gu10-indoor-flood-1pk/6000016953225) what the bulb looks like.

Comment: Why not just use the right lamp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Probably*, **but you don't want to.**

As comments mention, there are several factors which play into the maximum wattage. You don't know which factor(s) was/were the driving factor(s) in that rating so you have **no guarantee**.

The consequences of ignoring it could be as benign as a fuse breaking, or as bad as the insulation cooking and releasing toxic chemicals which cause health effects, or just getting it done with and burning down your house.

**Buying the right bulb is probably a lot cheaper.**